# iPhone / Android Emulators for PC that works with apk / ipa files

Tags: tools, android, iphone

We have an application coming up, which is a hybrid application developed using Phonegap. This will be available to us as APK and IPA packages.
I have been trying Android ADT Emulator, it is painfully slow and not easy to setup for newbies. But yes, it works.

My biggest problem is iPhone. We dont have a Mac around, and need to run emulator that runs on PC. Second problem is Andorid emulator, something which is faster would be better. Something that can directly accept APK files.

Summary:

1. Emulator for iPhone on **PC** that accepts .ipa files
2. Faster/easier to setup emulator for Android that accepts .apk files.

Comment: If you want to check the IPA on an iPhone set up some developer certificates through the Developer Center and add your iPhones as approved Devices.  Do Dev build for your approved devices once you are in a spot to check, as for submitting to iTunes you WILL need a Mac as the Application Loader used to upload to iTunes only comes with XCode as far as I know.

Comment: We finally gave up emulators all together, took statistics from Google and the local telecom regulatory about devices, and tested on the most commonly used real devices. It was a work around but we have some real testing coming up. Exploring more options. Every time, it's IPA :-(

Comment: Genymotion is a (free) very fast Android emulator that you can install APKs on. It's based on virtual box.

Answer (score 2):

**The best choice for Android is [GenyMotion](http://genymotion.com).**

> GenyMotion emulator runs really fast and supports all modern desktop OSes.
>   To install APK file you just drag-and-drop it on emulator window.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to build mobile apps, you need the right tools for the job. For the iPhone you need a mac. (Apple's license agreements require it.) You can get a mac mini from $599 US brand new, less if you go second hand. You will also need real test devices. Simulators alone are not good enough.

Comment: Thanks @bruce. Fortunately we got one Mac. But again, we don't have the source code as it is third party developed. Only ipa. As I understand, you need source to use the SDK emulator. Any idea about the tools that can be used on Mac for ipa packages?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [youwave](http://www.youwave.com/download) android emulator for test running apk files ,But remember that you cant run any script based Solutions, Alternatively you could speed up your android emulator by trying out solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

For Ios for testing native ipa packages there is no choice for windows upto now, one solution might be connecting your iphone and install iphone configuration utility for windows, This would give help you to inspect your application crash logs

Answer (score 0):

As far as android emulator is slower problem is concerned you could download android beta version and install using any virtual machine software it will load faster on android os.

Comment: welcome to SQA.  Could you add some more specific examples of emulators that might work for Supars?

Comment: The below link describes how to install the android os on PC.http://www.tecnigen.com/2013/07/08/install-android-os-on-pc-or-computer/ ...After installing the OS then you can install the apps and open faster just like one opens exe application in windows.If you are not interesetd in installing android os on pc may be the following link will give good idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try Bluestacks Emulator For Android. It works smoothly and also is the only free Android Emulator till today. http://www.iappforpc.com/2013/10/bluestacks-android-emulator-pc-app-game-player-offline-installer.html

Comment: Perhaps you should mention that Bluestacks is not a *testing* emulator, it is a playback emulator. The original poster may need a testing emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Run android .apk file using emulator follow the some basic step to click this link and follow the steps to configure the windows to run the .apk file through the android emulator

http://dotnethubs.blogspot.in/2013/09/how-i-can-run-apk-file-on-emulator.html

Comment: Hi, chitranjan, could you add some more information here to say how the solution at the link addresses the specific problems the original poster mentioned? A one-line "click on this link" doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily solve this issue by downloading emulators which is Given in this below given post, Have a look to the post and you will find it by your own!
http://temcam.com/2013/10/12/download-subway-surfers-for-pc-windows-78xp/

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out, but it would have been bigger help if you could simply mention  Bluestacks instead of the link to this long blog. Bluestacks anyway will not work.

Comment: @Karan, could you please edit your answer to mention Bluestacks in the body of the answer - links don't always stay relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I think by now you have all your answers.
But if you have not.

If you want to properly do a QA on your Mobile Application. You need the real devices. That is the most perfect way to test it.

If you can't then next best thing would be to use cloud based testing providers.

If you are still convinced about stickiing to the emulator scenario. Then..

- **For Android**: Android SDK emulator is your best choice. All the other emulators you will get are designed for some specific person or other. But none for testing. Apart from the original stock emulator.
- **For iOS Device**: I must try to convince you to either get a iOS device itself. Or a MAC. The best emulator (and arguable the only authentic) you will get is the one that comes with xcode. Anything else is really not recommendable for any kind of QA.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily download Android emulator known as Bluestacks from here and install it on your computer - http://www.androidappsonpc.net/download-bluestacks-app-player-for-windows-and-mac/

Comment: Arbaz, two other answers mention Bluestacks, and the original poster has indicated that Bluestacks does not meet his needs.